# iPhone: How to set repeat daily/hourly local notification?

Tags: iphone, ios4, local, notifications, repeat

I want to test add local notification. I want it repeat daily/hourly. How can I do that?

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

 // Get the current date
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

 // Break the date up into components
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit |       NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit )
           fromDate:now];

NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit)
           fromDate:now];


 // Set up the fire time
NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

[dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
[dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
[dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];

[dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
 [dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
 [dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]+10];

 // Notification will fire in one minute

NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
[dateComps release];

UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (localNotif == nil)
    return;

localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

 // Notification details
localNotif.alertBody = @"Hello World";

 // Set the action button
localNotif.alertAction = @"View";
localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

applicationIconBadgeNumber++;

localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = applicationIconBadgeNumber;

 // Schedule the notification
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
[localNotif release];
```

Comment: You could try formatting your code properly.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to set the Notifications at a particular time on daily ... .then you need to set the notification **repeatInterval** property.iOS handles of it;s own about the notification.Just add this single line ...which you missed out. Otherwise you code is fine & will work.

```
notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
```

Comment: Can we Use random Time of Day with NSDayCalendarUnit ??    i want to do daily local notification once in a day at random Basis ... PLease Help

Comment: @shaqirsaiyed: you'll probably have to manually create each random day's firetime, this isn't a normal "repeat interval".

Answer (score 2):

Your code would be much simpler if you used dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:.

(dateByAddingTimeInterval: does not handle calendars properly, e.g. time zone changes.)

If you want it to repeat, I think you have to add several, or re-add them when your app is next launched. Otherwise, a notification that repeated every second would be incredibly annoying.

Answer (score 1):

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (localNotif == nil) return;

NSDate *fireTime = [[NSDate date]   dateByAddingTimeInterval:900]; // 15 minutes

localNotif.fireDate = fireTime;
localNotif.alertBody = @"15 min reached";
localNotif.repeatInterval=kCFCalendarUnitMinute;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```