# ios how to change an image at specific time

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I have an image that i want to display as a sun during daytime i.e. from 6am to 6pm, and moon from 6pm to 6am.

I have successfully implemented that but the problem is the image would not change when it reaches the specified time unless re-run the apps before the image change itself.

I don't want to use NSTimer to check the time, like every second. The only possible solution i think of is using NSLocalNotification but I'm a newbiew to it. any help? =)

```
-(void) dayOrNight
{

NSDate* date                = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter* dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HHmm"];
NSString* dateString        = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
NSNumber* currentTime       = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[dateString intValue]];
NSNumber* daytime           = [NSNumber numberWithInt:600];
NSNumber* nightime          = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1800];
NSLog(@"current time: %@",dateString);

dayNight = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(265, 10, 50, 50)];


    if ( [currentTime doubleValue] >= [daytime doubleValue] && [currentTime doubleValue] <= [nightime doubleValue] ) 
    {
    dayNight.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Sun.png"];
    }

    else 
    {
    dayNight.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"moon.png"];
    }


[self.view addSubview:dayNight];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local notification should be fine, I guess.
[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1) you can get all needed code snippets to implement execution of `dayOrNight` method at needed time. Also, you shouldn't add new view every time you change the picture.

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing out my silly mistake. anyway, i found a way to do this. i use NSLocalNotification to get the time and then use NSNotification to get to my change image method. well, not that elegant but at least worked.

Comment: What do you mean - "get the time"? You can just create 2 notifications - to be fired at 6am and at 6pm and make each of it repeat itself every day. Like  [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426882/iphone-how-to-set-repeat-daily-hourly-local-notification) You even don't need to know what time is it then you create notification, just the day. Use NSDateComponents to create needed date for first fire.

Comment: by "get the time", i mean to know what the current time is, and yes, i only need 2 notifications. thanks for the advice! =)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible to do without NSTimer. U can set refreshTime by yourself (for example 1 min/ if u don`t want to do it every second)))
Or u can call this method in other methods, which are working in your class every time...

maybe u have some object, which u use during your class is working...

```
-(IBAction)myButtonWhichIPressDuringIworkHere {
///some actions
[self dayOrNight];
}
```

In other case you should to use NSTimer

Comment: thanks for reply, but i don't want to use NS Timer as it really isn't a good way to do it. I have found a way to do it though using local notification n nsnotification. =)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to check the time at every second.

this is *one of the possible solutions*. it has been **tested on real device** only.

---

your **UIYourViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSDate *_currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *_dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd' 06:00AM +0000'"]; // set the morning date here
    NSString *_morningDateString = [_dateFormatter stringFromDate:_currentDate];
    [_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd' 06:00PM +0000'"]; // set the evening date here
    NSString *_eveningDateString = [_dateFormatter stringFromDate:_currentDate];

    [_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mma zzz"];
    NSDate *_morningDate = [_dateFormatter dateFromString:_morningDateString];
    NSDate *_eveningDate = [_dateFormatter dateFromString:_eveningDateString];

    NSTimeInterval _intervalToMorningDate = [_morningDate timeIntervalSinceDate:_currentDate];
    NSTimeInterval _intervalToEveningDate = [_eveningDate timeIntervalSinceDate:_currentDate];

    if (_intervalToMorningDate > 0) {
        // now it is night
        dayNight.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"moon.png"];
        [self performSelector:@selector(replaceTheBackgoundForMorning) withObject:nil afterDelay:_intervalToMorningDate];
    } else {
        // now it is daytime
        dayNight.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Sun.png"];
        [self performSelector:@selector(replaceTheBackgoundForEvening) withObject:nil afterDelay:_intervalToEveningDate];
    }

}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
}
```

and finally you should add them to your same **.m** file:

```
-(void)replaceTheBackgoundForMorning {
    // reaplce the backgound here
    dayNight.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Sun.png"];
}

- (void)replaceTheBackgoundForEvening {
    // reaplce the backgoung here
    dayNight.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"moon.png"];
}
```

Comment: this is a good idea but when i test on my device, it won't automatically change the image when it reaches 6am or 6pm.