# LocalNotifiction for wakeup application

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

In my application i want to set local notifiaction on a particular time if my application killed from background else if my application in  running condition then i dan't want to show localnotification

I have written code for local notification

```
NSCalendar *calendar1 = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

        // Get the current date
        NSDate *pickerDate1 =self.dateEvening;//[self.dateEvening dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*1];// [self.pickerView date];

        // Break the date up into components
        NSDateComponents *dateComponents1 = [calendar1 components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit ) 
                                                       fromDate:pickerDate1];
        NSDateComponents *timeComponents1 = [calendar1 components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit ) 
                                                       fromDate:pickerDate1];


        NSDateComponents *dateComps1 = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        [dateComps1 setDay:[dateComponents1 day]];
        [dateComps1 setMonth:[dateComponents1 month]];
        [dateComps1 setYear:[dateComponents1 year]];
        [dateComps1 setHour:[timeComponents1 hour]];

        [dateComps1 setMinute:[timeComponents1 minute]];
        [dateComps1 setSecond:[timeComponents1 second]];
        NSDate *itemDate1 = [calendar1 dateFromComponents:dateComps1];
        [dateComps1 release];

        UILocalNotification *localNotif1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        if (localNotif1 == nil)
            return;
        localNotif1.fireDate = itemDate1;
        localNotif1.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        localNotif1.alertBody = @"Open application";


        localNotif1.alertAction = @"View";

        localNotif1.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;




        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif1];
        [localNotif1 release];
```

Above code works fine if application will  close from background but if my application in running condition then I don't want local notifications to be fired.

Comment: Your english is really hard to understand, but I guess you forgot that if an app in the foreground the localnotifiation will trigger the `- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification` in your app delgate and you will have to inform the user your self. There is not message posted by iOS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone: How to set repeat daily/hourly local notification?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426882/iphone-how-to-set-repeat-daily-hourly-local-notification)